# CRM 2011 Remove unwanted menu entry

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I want to remove the "New" option in a entry on the main menu. Its that little right arrow that allows the user to see this menu at all, I'd be okay with completely removing that.

[image: unwanted menu entry]

Here is what the element looks like in my sitemap:

```
  <SubArea Id="nav_cases" Entity="incident"
 DescriptionResourceId="Cases_SubArea_Description"
 GetStartedPanePath="Cases_Web_User_Visor.html"
 GetStartedPanePathAdmin="Cases_Web_Admin_Visor.html"
 GetStartedPanePathOutlook="Cases_Outlook_User_Visor.html"
 GetStartedPanePathAdminOutlook="Cases_Outlook_Admin_Visor.html" />
```

And based on the [sitemap documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328498.aspx) I don't think I can acheive this with the xml.

So I guess I want to know if this is possible? Or is this just part of the framework I can't get at? Is there some clever javascript I can do?

The reason I want to remove it is because these are childen in a parent:child relationship and we only want users to create them from the context of the parent record.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't think there is a way to do this (unless you go way unsupported and are not online).

An alternative would be to have JavaScript on the form that immediately prompts the user for the parent record.  That's probably the approach I would take.

Comment: Also, you can throw an exception via a plugin registered to the create event if this entity is created without a reference to a parent to make sure it's handled server side as well.

Comment: Darn. When the parent record isnt passed in to the child form then the javascipt to pop the lookup is a good idea, Paul. I will enforce the constraint with plugin code, Peter. Thanks guys. Too bad I cant just block the case entirely.

Comment: Don't forget that this workaround will mean that the user creates a record outside the parent context, then you are forcing them to choose a parent (making the lookup mandatory would do that without code). However, this still won't map attributes / field values from parent to child, so you might want to look at something like this to help out: http://crm2011attributemap.codeplex.com/