# Hiding a link in the sitemap based on security role in crm 2011 using javascript

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, sitemap, security-roles

Is there any way to hide a link in the SiteMap in CRM 2011 using javascript? The link is not that of an entity. It's basically an injected link which opens up a custom HTML page in the dashboard. Is there any way I can probably wire up a javascript function so that the link can be made visible/hidden by invoking that javascript function?

If that is not possible, could there possibly be a workaround for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You *can* restrict users' access to a `SubArea` by using the `Privilege` element. If a user doesn't have the right privilege, that `SubArea` won't show, though this is obviously not something that you trigger programmatically on load.

```
<SubArea Id="search" Icon="" Url="http://www.dropbox.com">
  <Titles>
    <Title LCID="1033" Title="Dropbox Search" />
  </Titles>
  <Descriptions>
    <Description LCID="1033" Description="Dropbox searching." />
  </Descriptions>
  <Privilege Entity="product" Privilege="Create" />
</SubArea>
```

Answer (score 1):

The [sitemap XML documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9788825/crm-2011-remove-unwanted-menu-entry) doesn't have anything to disable a link based on javascript.

I've ask a [somewhat similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9788825/crm-2011-remove-unwanted-menu-entry), with a less than ideal conclusion.. The sitemap is pretty locked down.

If the privilege solution Peter points out is not going to be compatible with your situation, I suppose your HTML web resource will have to handle the blocking in the page's onload event.